# Duplicate number and it value in column EXCEL

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates, conditional-formatting

I have an excel file with two columns. Excel screenshot below:

[image]

What I want is an Excel VBA is :

[image]

I did it with pivot table and it works , but i really want to have it with VBA because I have a lot of values.

I'm not good with Excel VBA so I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: sort it on column A, then use conditional formatting to hide the duplicates.

Comment: Please attempt it yourself and ask for help with your problems... Typically people here wont just provide you code without you attempting it first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Sub wqewrty()
    With Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                    Key2:=.Columns(2), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
        With .Columns(1).Offset(1, 0)
            .FormatConditions.Delete
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$A2=$A1"
            .FormatConditions(1).NumberFormat = ";;;"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

I've assumed that you wanted to use column B as a secondary sort key to the primary sort key on column A. If not, remove the second key and order from the .Sort command.

[image]

Comment: Did something good happen today?  I did not expect an answer.

Comment: Sometimes I just to like to see if I can type out the code without mistakes.